# Problem on Griffiths: Finding potential

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, potential, dielectric, dipole

[image]

For this problem, I understand that I have to use separation of variables to do this question. However, I was confused by the boundary condition in the solution.

[image]

Shouldn't the boundary condition be $\epsilon_0\frac{\partial V_{out}}{\partial r}-\epsilon\frac{\partial V_{in}}{\partial r}=-\sigma_f$?

Comment: Where did you get that solution?  (It does indeed look wrong, as the discontinuity in $\hat{n}\cdot\vec{\nabla}V$ certainly has be given by the *total* surface charge density $\sigma$, not the bound $\sigma_{b}$.)

Comment: @Buzz I got it somewhere from the internet. I have no idea how they get this boundary condition.